# Open a PDF file before it is finished downloading

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf

I am writing a WPF software using .NET 4.5 to show the PDF Data in a Viewer. I am showing the PDF on the viewer directly from the server. That means before actually the PDf shows up in the viewer, the pdf is downloaded on the device and then when it finishes downloading, it shows on the viewer.

Do anybody has a idea on how to show the downloaded data on the viewer when it's being downloaded. I mean if the PDF file has 100 pages and it has finish downloading some data or pages then it starts showing some pages at first and it continue downloading the PDF on the background.

PS: I am using GDPicture as a viewer.

Comment: You are looking for a concept known as *Linearization* aka *Fast Web-View.* Linearization is typically a process that you perform *after* the complete document has been created. It involves reordering PDF objects so that all the objects necessary for page 1 are transmitted first, followed by an xref table for page 1, then all the objects necessary for page 2 are transmitted,... As this process usually requires that all the objects are known (e.g, after finishing page 1, you may not be able to pass the font yet), it is usually not supported in tools that create PDF on-the-fly.

Answer (score -1):

Save the file as Web Optimized

[Optimizing PDFs](http://talkingpdf.org/optimizing-pdfs-to-reduce-file-size/)

[Enable Fast Web View](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7f52.w.html)